# webdriver hangs for some url on .get (IE)

Tags: internet-explorer, webdriver, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

I have Selenium 3.14.4
IEDriver 3.15

For some url when I call driver.get(), webdriver just sits there even though the page is done loading. In the end we get the error "Command line server for IE driver has stopped working"

I've tried both 32bit and 64bit of the IEdriver - same issue

When I downgrade the IE driver back to 2.53.1 it works fine with no error.

Any one know if this is a known defect for IEdriver 3.X ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found this as a known defect for IEDriver 3.X. But you could try the latest stable version of Selenium Server which is **3.141.59** and the recommended Internet Explorer Driver Server version **3.150.1** in [this page](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/). Besides, please try to check if you have meet the required configuration for IEDriver in [this page](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration).